# Sum tuples of Num instances

Tags: haskell, numbers, tuples

Is there a standard way to sum tuples of `Num`s?

```
(1, 2) + (3, 4)
```

I think there are many ways to achieve this. To name a few: writing your own function/operator, making `(Num a, Num b) => (a, b)` an instance of `Num`, wrapping a tuple in a `newtype` and so on.

It seems like this problem should emerge regularly, but I don't see any standard solutions at google or SO search results. Am I missing something?

Comment: [`biliftA2 (+)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html#v:biliftA2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space).

```
Prelude> :m +Data.VectorSpace
Prelude Data.VectorSpace> (1,2) ^+^ (3,4)
(4,6)
Prelude Data.VectorSpace> (1,2,5) ^+^ (3,4,6)
(4,6,11)
Prelude Data.VectorSpace> ((1,2),(9,8)) ^+^ ((3,4),(6,7))
((4,6),(15,15))
Prelude Data.VectorSpace> ((1,2),(9,8)) ^+^ ((3,4),0)  -- dimension mismatch

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num (Integer, Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Answer (score 5):

Pair implements Monoid if both elements are Monoids.

For Num you can use newtype wrapper to choose Monoid

```
> :m +Data.Monoid
> (Sum 1, Sum 2) <> (Sum 3, Sum 4)
(Sum {getSum = 4},Sum {getSum = 6})
```

You can then add the two numbers together by uncurrying `<>`:

```
> uncurry (<>) $ (Sum 1, Sum 2) <> (Sum 3, Sum 4)
Sum {getSum = 10}
```